# WebHttpBinding in Silverlight 4

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I know SL 3 didn't have this but from reading about SL 4, it sounds like it supports WebHttpBinding for REST...

But how do I create one in code? I can't find WebHttpBinding anywhere in the ServiceModel.* assemblies for Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the webHttpBinding per se in SL4:

> No analog to the WebHttpBinding  provided in WCF is provided. To access pure HTTP, REST, RSS/Atom, or AJAX services from Silverlight 3, use the techniques described in Accessing HTTP and REST-Based Services Directly, such as the WebClient class. To access ASP.NET AJAX services, see Accessing ASP.NET AJAX Services.

(source: [Silverlight and WCF Feature Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470110%28VS.95%29.aspx))

but you *can* access a WCF REST service since it's really "just" XML over HTTP.

Check out this MSDN library article here:

[Accessing HTTP and REST-Based Services Directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197947%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)